# Is $E = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid xy \leq1 \}$ connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm trying to solve this point set topology problem.

I need to prove whether or not $E_1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid xy \leq 1 \}$ is connected. We are using the euclidean topology, as usual. I feel like this set is connected, hence I tried to prove it by contradiction, but I struggled to find one.

Moreover, I need to find the connected components of $E_2 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid xy \geq 1\}$. Here, I think that $E_2$ is not connected itself, so I cannot find its connected components. Am I right?

Comment: What do you mean you cannot find its connected components? If you draw a picture you can easily see that $E_2$ has 4 connected components.

Comment: But is $E_2$ connected? I thought that if a space is not connected then it doesn't have connected components. To me $E_2$ seems split in two parts, hence the non connectedness.

Comment: Any space has connected components; it is connected if and only if it has exactly one connected component.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Super useful :)

Answer (score 3):

Hint 1. Note that if $(x,y)\in E_1$ then $(tx,ty)\in E_1$ for all $t\in [0,1]$, that is the segment with endpoints $(x,y)$ and $(0,0)$ is in $E_1$.
Hence $E_1$ is a [star domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain).

Hint 2. $E_2$ is not connected: show that $(1,1)\in E_2$ and $(-1,-1)\in E_2$ are in different  connected components.

Comment: Very nice, I did not think to use that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are three obvious ways to prove a set is connected:

1. Write the set as the continuous image of a connected set and apply the intermediate value theorem.
2. Show that the set is path connected. You can do this by:

   i. showing the set is convex, or

   ii. finding a path between any two points in the set, or

   iii. finding a path between any point and some fixed point (such as the origin).
3. Try to apply the definition.

In this case, method 2.iii works.

For the second question, note that connected component means a maximal connected subset, not that the original set is connected. In this case, $E_2$ has two connected components:

$$ \{(x,y) : x \ge 0, xy \ge 1\} \text{ and } \{(x,y) : x \le 0, xy \ge 1\}. $$

Hopefully the picture makes this clear.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions for future proofs. Much appreciated. :)